# How to run two different tests in Googletest

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, googletest

Suppose I have two/many different tests need to be carried out in gtest in two iteration.
So, how to carryout the same? I tried my approch but it fails.
I wrote,

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(repeat) = 2; //may be 2 or 3 or so on...
switch(i) //int i = 1;
{
case 1:
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "*first*:*second*";
i++; break;
case 2:
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "*third*:*fourth*";
i++; break;
and so on............
```

But Google test is taking only the `"*first*:*second*"` and runs two times.
Please help me. My reqiurement is Gtest should run all the test cases one by one.
e.g first it will execute `case 1:` then `case 2:` and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using `::testing::GTEST_FLAG(repeat)`

However, you could achieve your goal with something like:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int RunTests(int iteration) {
  switch(iteration) {
    case 1:  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "*first*:*second*"; break;
    case 2:  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "*third*:*fourth*"; break;
    default: ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "*";
  }
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  int final_result(0);
  for (int i(0); i < 3; ++i) {
    int result(RunTests(i));
    if (result != 0)
      final_result = result;
  }
  return final_result;
}
```

I'm not sure how gtest calculates the return value of `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` when `GTEST_FLAG(repeat)` is used, but here `main` will return `0` if all tests pass, otherwise it will return the last non-zero value of the `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` invocations.

Comment: :- Thanks for the great help. But the moment `control` sees `InitGoogletest` without any `preconditions` (like filter) it starts run all the test cases then it goes to filtered test cases.
I found a solution. Please have a look below.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Glad you got your solution.  Although `InitGoogleTest` isn't quite doing what you think.  It only has an effect the first time you call it - all subsequent calls are no-ops.  You can safely move it to before the `for` loop in your answer.  In my answer, you get no filter the first time because I started the loop at 0 rather than 1, and there is no `case 0`, so it uses the `default` case, i.e. `"*"`.

Comment: :-Yes, you are right. I did the same putting `InitGoogleTest` before `for` loop, and things are woking fine. But one question, what is the difference between keeping `InitGoogleTest` inside and before `for` loop (except `init-ing` `GoogleTest` many times till condition fails)?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak There's no real problem with calling `InitGoogleTest` as many times as you like.  It only "does" something the first time you call it.  Every time after that, all it does is check to see if it's been called previously, and if so returns immediately without doing anything further.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 1;
        vector<string> str;
        str.push_back("*first*:*second*");
        str.push_back("*third*:*fourth*");
        str.push_back("*fifth.fifthtestname*");
        for(i = 0; i != str.size(); i++)
        {
            ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = str.at(i);
             InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
             RUN_ALL_TESTS();
            // getchar();
        }
        getchar();
}
```